# Показывать баннер на всех своих сайтах

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Дорогие друзья будьте добры мне помочь, у меня есть php скрипт там показывается баннер допустим

```
 http:/site.ru/sk.php
```

В нём у меня выводится баннер, в чём суть вопроса я хочу что бы данный баннер показывался на всех моих сайтах, можно реализовать это что бы 1 строчкой было, остальные сайты у меня все на html написаны, можно это реализовать что бы было вот так:

```
<script src="http://www.site.ru/sk.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: да можно, гуглим CORS после этого в js вы можете получать данные для своего баннера через ajax, только вот насчет установки баннера друзьям - друзья должны вам очень доверять в этом случае, т.к. вы получите доступ к браузерам их пользователей.

Answer (score 2):

Тебе поможет технология [SSI (server side includes)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html) - древняя просто жуть.

На страницах HTML выбери место, где должен вставляться баннер и вставь инструкцию

```
<!--#include virtual="/path/to/banners.shtml" -->
```

Создай файл /path/to/banners.shtml и вставь в него строку

```
<script src="http://www.site.ru/sk.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Создай файл с именем .htaccess в корневой папке твоего сайта и добавь туда такие строки

```
Options +Includes
AddHandler server-parsed .html
AddType text/html .html
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
```

---

Ещё вариант - прицеплять javascript с банером с помощью PHP. Но такой банер либо приписывается в конец страницы, либо выводится сверху в блоке типа "popup" - оба варианта выглядят лишними на странице.

Создай файл с именем .htaccess в корневой папке твоего сайта и добавь туда такие строки

```
# все страницы c расширением htm и html запускать через PHP
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

# Прицепить скрипт в самом начале
php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/header.php"

# Прицепить скрипт в конце
php_value auto_append_file "/path/to/footer.php"
```

В инструкциях нужно указать путь к файлам. Можно вставить обе инструкции, а можно только одну из этих.

В файле /path/to/footer.php можно написать обычный текст HTML, например

```
<script src="http://www.site.ru/sk.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: У меня получается сайты на разном хосте + я хотел друзьям на сайты разместить есть легче вариант ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <iframe src="banner.php" width="468" height="60" align="left">
```

Comment: у меня не обычный баннер а всплывает с боку сайта

Comment: У меня всплывающий баннер я хотел разместить его к друзьям но весь код вставлять слишком геморойно вот думаю может есть способ какой то ?

Comment: И опять я хочу хранить все файлы на своём сервере так как у меня к базе подключёна база и текст в баннере всегда меняться будет, я устанавливал ads script php (http://www.phpkobo.com/text_ad.php), в нём такую ссылку вставляешь <script type='text/javascript' src='http://test13.ru/cn/cn.php?id=1001'></script> и баннер показывается можно как то также сделать ?